# How to boot my SSD from another PC?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am moving temporarily and I don't want to move my case with me. Can I just take my SSD with me and be able to boot Windows 7 from it on another similar PC?

My current PC:

- CPU: Intel i7 860 3.4 Ghz
- Motherboard: GIGABYTE P55 USB3
- RAM: CORSAIR 12 GB 1600 MHz

Comment: @Matthew Williams : It's a second language :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, you could - but I'd not recommend it.

Windows will automatically install new drivers to match the hardware of the new machine (because if it doesn't, you'll probably find it barely functions). That can be problematic in itself, though: some hardware in the new machine may not work properly, which may leave you manually reinstalling drivers and trying to disable no-longer-needed drivers that Windows didn't correctly handle. Further, you're likely to have the same problem when you later put the drive *back*, by which point you'll have doubly messed up your machine.

If it's data that you want to keep hold of, I'd suggest buying a USB drive caddy so you can plug your SSD in to another machine and access your data. If it's the OS, apps and settings you're worried about, and you really don't want to take the machine, you could leave it on and connected somewhere where you can access it remotely (e.g. use Teamviewer, VNC, RDP over the internet from another machine).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the hardware is not too different this should work.
See this other question about similar things:  [2 identical PCs - can I swap a single hard drive between and expect Windows 7/XP to work?](https://superuser.com/questions/446032/2-identical-pcs-can-i-swap-a-single-hard-drive-between-and-expect-windows-7-xp/446058#446058)

Please bear in mind that if there are many hardware differences Windows 7 might require re-activation. (Different type CPU and motherboard chip-set are almost certainly going to cause this.)

Dan Puzey's concerns in the other answer regarding the system getting messed up are valid, but in general, as long as you stay within 1 main chip-set/CPU generation it is usually no problem. And don't upgrade to much newer hardware.
Don't try to move disks from a Core2Duo to a Core-i system. Between Core-i's should be OK. From Core-i to Core2Duo is usually also not an issue (and then returning to the original hardware should be Ok too).

Don't swap between AMD and Intel CPU's !!! At least not unless you have a very good backup. It may work but usually the system will just blue-screen. And it is quite possible the install won't work anymore on the original hardware either after such an attempt.